# Is it possible to remotely force a session expiration on other machines like gmail?

Tags: support

I am afraid I forgot my SO account logged (with remember me / keep me logged in) in a public computer. :(

Comment: I don't think this is available as a tool. You could E-Mail `team@stackoverflow.com` and see what they can do. (Although shouldn't temporarily replacing your OpenID kick out any existing sessions? I'm not sure, maybe someone who knows can confirm.)

Answer (score 20):

Just [logout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout) normally; it will log out of all your sessions:

[image: Clicking Log Out will clear our cookies and log you out on all devices.]

Comment: There is a log-out page? I didn't even know that it existed!

Comment: @thkala Mouse over your name in the top bar